# StructureMap exception: No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I'm receiving the following error from StructureMap when initializing my ObjectFactory.

> StructureMap.StructureMapException occurred   HResult=-2146232832
>   Message=StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No Default Instance defined
>   for PluginFamily
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.Type, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Func`2[[System.Data.Entity.DbContext,
>   EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   Source=StructureMap
>   ErrorCode=202   StackTrace:
>          at StructureMap.BuildSession.<.ctor>b__0(Type t) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line
>   33   InnerException:

From previous answers, it looks like I'm missing a reference to an assembly, but I'm including a heck of a lot now.  Here's my full initialization statement:

```
     ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                                   {
                                       x.Scan(scan =>
                                                  {
                                                      scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                                      scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                                      scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                                                  });
                                       x.For<IRepositoryProvider>().Use<RepositoryProvider>();
                                       x.For<IDataUow>().Use<DataInterface>();
                                       x.Forward<IDataUow, IDisposable>();
                                       x.For<RepositoryFactories>().Singleton();
                                   });
```

Comment: This indicate that something that the container tries to resolve has a dependency on an `IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, Object>>`. Check the constructors of the types you have wired up and the constructors for all types they are depending on. I have run into these kinds of problems when scanning all Assemblies from base directory and applying default conventions, because StructureMap often will pick up types in the components and frameworks that are referenced. Try removing the scan for all assemblies and add the registrations manually until you find the offending type.

Comment: Thanks!  That's helpful... A real pain do do in this case, but helpful info nonetheless.